# Error while adding Gmail Background dependency

Tags: java, android, background-process

I want to send an email in background in my android app. For this I am using [Gmail Background](https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground).

But when I try to add `compile 'com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0'` in dependencies it gives me error

> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0

What should I do to resolve this error ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you also need to add the corresponding repository into the project's `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // that's the one missing.
    }
}
```

[GmailBackground](https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground)

Comment: It's working but giving error on `this` at `BackgroundMail.newBuilder(this)`

Comment: @MrFaisal try `SomeActivity.this` or `getContext()` ...you need to pass some kind of `Context` class (that example on GitHub just assumes, that the code runs within some Activity class).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "compile" by "implementation" as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

> The compile and runtime configurations have been removed with Gradle
> 7.0. Please refer to the upgrade guide how to migrate to implementation and api configurations`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).